# asp.net session data lost on postback of the page in windows XP

Tags: asp.net, session

I have a ascx page on load of the page I save few data in the HttpContext Session, on selection of data in the screen I reload the page with relevant data for the selection. Until here the data in the session exists. But on click of a button say ok button to navigate to next page. all the data in the session is lost. But the same works in windows 7 and windows server 2008 not in windows XP. are there any configuration difference in windows 7 and XP. I am trying to figure out the cause for some time now any help on this would be great.

Thanks

Arvind

Answer (score 1):

We need to see your web.config, specifically the sessionState section.

There are a number of reasons you could be losing your session data... are you sure your app domain is not recycling?

Comment: Thaks for the reply. How do i know if app domain and worker process is not recycling

Comment: Easiest way to check is to put a log message of some kind in App_Start.  You can also use Perfmon I'm sure, but I couldn't tell you which counter it is.